# Composite nodes being ignored when rendering from command line

Tags: node-editor, command-line, compositing-nodes

I am trying to render an animation using cycles from the command line but my composite nodes are being ignored. The images look ok, just the denoising and glare are missing. In blender on my other machine when hitting f12 the nodes are being applied correctly.

I am running the command `blender -b file.blend -t 8 -o renders/frame_### -a`

This is my node setup for compositing [image: node setup in compositing]

Comment: They do work when not using the command line, you’ve tested?

Comment: you you provide your blend file?

Comment: Have you taken a look at the command prompt when you hit f12? Not sure if that would display more info.

Comment: @ZargulTheWizard Yes, when I am in blender normally they work fine and are being applied when I hit f12 to render a frame.

Comment: @Hendriks3D I am trying to use different machines, one is a linux server which I am trying to run the command line version of blender on, the other is my workstation pc. I don't know if any debugging locally with my pc will help the issue.

Comment: The same thing happened to me. Can someone answer this question? Both Use Nodes and Use for Rendering options are turned on and will work normally when rendered in the GUI, but will be ignored in the command line.